# In Excel what is equivalent function of table function in R

Tags: excel

For example I have a cell:

```
A
B
B
A
C
```

I want to have a summary of total count of each character:

```
A 2
B 2
C 1
```

How can I do this in Excel?

Comment: I haven't used excel for a while, but I believe what you are looking for is achieved in excel with a Pivot table.

Comment: Or maybe using `countif`, if you create the first column with unique ids like A, B, C in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert > PivotTable

Select your column as the row field and as the value field. Change the value field calculation from sum to count if it defaults to sum.